# Habit tracking app that supports weekly time-based goals

Tags: android, productivity

I am looking for a goal resp. habit tracking (Android) app that allows for goals  of the form:

> Run for at least 2h a week.
>
> Be on Facebook at most 3h a week.

I have tried several apps, but they either have yes/no or number-of-good-days goals for weeks, or have only daily goals to begin with.

Ideally, I would also be able to set a yearly goal of the form "fulfill this daily/weekly goal at least x times".

HabitBull comes closest: it allows to set a time goal for days and lets you specify the number of successful days per week.

Answer (score 1):

The [Rewire App](http://www.rewireapp.io/) has features to support this:
When adding a habit, choose a 'flexible' schedule and specify number of hours per week.
Then while logging, specify number of minutes completed per cycle.

In addition, to control time spent on specific apps / websites, you can check out [freedom.to](https://freedom.to/).

Comment: Is this a premium-only feature? In the free version, I only see "num days per week/month/year"? To be clear, can I log per day towards a per-week goal?

Comment: Sorry this doesn't exactly meet your requirement but:

This is a free feature. Under num days per week/month/year, there is another section "How many times do you want to perform this habit?" The default is 0.0 times per day - but you can change times to hours. Then when you log your daily performance, you can log how much of this step is completed. 

I don't think this is exactly what you want though. 
You can also try writing to the developers and see if they can help - I wrote to them once and they were very responsive.

Comment: I can not reproduce. See [here](http://imgur.com/a/Zmgzj): I can not enter the `num` field before "times a day", and when I tap "times" I get that notice asking me to go premium.

Comment: That's strange. I do not have a premium account, but it allows me to enter this field. See [here](http://postimg.org/image/3xj9hu7c1/) and [here](http://postimg.org/image/trogtvhy9/).  I am using Version 9.3.2. You can probably try and contact them: RandomeStudios@gmail.com.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'll stick to CSV files for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a smartwatch. Then the watch and the associated smartphone app would remind you, and keep track of your fitness goals and activity goals/achievements, provided you wear the watch all the time. It can also track health parameters, e.g. sleep patterns.

Most (All?) smartwatches cannot track how much time you spend on Facebook, of course. 
You'd need different software for this, probably for each device you have in use.

Maybe there *is* a watch/app combination that can actually do this. I haven't checked, that's impossible to keep track of, new watches/gadgets get released every so often, and the apps get updated, too.

Comment: So how does this answer my question? I'm (or rather, was) very specificaly looking for a way to track arbitrary goals/habits, not restricted to the things a watch could track automatically, plus I was very specific about looking for an Android app, not an expensive hardware gadget.

Comment: It *partially* answers your question. Many gadgets are not *that* expensive, and they usually come with a free Android app that have more storage space and serve as long-time data storage to capture workout/trip history. They also come with goal-setting features (e.g. walk 7000 steps/day) set to reasonable defaults.  I'm still convinced that the scenario "Run for at least 2h a week", which you explicitlymentioned as #1, can be best tracked, automatically, very ccurately and specifically with a smartwatch. Wearing a smartphone during all physical activities is inpractical in my opinion.